# Why my code is wrong? I need to hide special images

Tags: jquery, attr

I try this code, but he dosent work -

```
var $this = $('img');
if ($this.attr('src') == '/templates/babydrive/dleimages/no_image.jpg') {
    $this.css('display', 'none');
}
```

What is problem? Help plz!

Comment: That code only looks at the first img, that's what's wrong.

Comment: Use `$('img').each()`

Comment: Please describe the expected results and what goes wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to check for all images. You were checking only for the 1st image.

```
var images = $('img');

images.each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src') == '/templates/babydrive/dleimages/no_image.jpg') {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking for the first 'IMG' tag it sees. Use CSS in your markup to more specifically point out the image (aka, use an ID if it's just a single image, or a class if otherwise, such as a group of images with that class).

Answer (score 0):

Set the display property on each image based on it's source :

```
$('img').css('display', function() {
    return $(this).attr('src')==='/templates/babydrive/dleimages/no_image.jpg' ? 'none' : 'inline';
});
```

Comment: That exactly what i need! Thank you! Jquery is fully mystery!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter()` to find the elements matching a function call:

```
$('.img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src') == '/templates/babydrive/dleimages/no_image.jpg';
}).hide();
```

You could also put the `src` in the selector:

```
$('.img[src=/templates/babydrive/dleimages/no_image.jpg]').hide();
```